# How to use YQL to get sectors from Yahoo Finance?

Tags: yql, finance, yahoo-finance

I found out about YQL and would like to use it to get a list of financial sectors. I went to the YQL console and tried to use the `yahoo.finance.sectors` table:

[select * from yahoo.finance.sectors](https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.sectors&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=)

The results are "null". I'm assuming the data is available. What is wrong with the way I'm calling YQL?

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with your statement, there is no data for that table, if you execute something like `select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol = 'IBM'` you do get data back..

Comment: There seems to be some past issues with this table.. see this [link](https://github.com/yql/yql-tables/issues/445)